# PHP array_rand not working properly

Tags: php

My randomize function does not work properly.
I have an array which is getting randomized.

The array contains three values but only two are chosen each time.

```
$sterren = array("3","4","5");
$sterrenr = array_rand($sterren, 1);
$sterrenf = $sterren[$sterrenr[0]];
echo $sterrenf;
```

During the loop when outputting echo $sterrenf only the values 3 and 4 appear but no value 5.
Anyone any ideas ?

Comment: Check the first example, you should be accessing element 0 of the return array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: Also, not the easiest to read variable names :P

Comment: Thanks but im accessing element 0 as you can see.

Comment: Dude, don't edit it to make the answer in the question. You can answer your own question but if you edit it then the question is lost for future askers.

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3 : as FaddishWorm suggested, reading the php manual would help you to get a better understanding

Comment: I did read it an I adjusted my question above to array_rand($sterren, 3);

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3 : then yu should not be having the confusion of whether the function would return a random key or a shuffled array.

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3: Please don't change the question after it's already been answered. Instead, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Yes thank you but I think its a server side problem.
I used you demo to change and it outputs 3,4 or 5 when using array_rand($sterren, 3); however in my script on the server only returning 3.

Comment: After testing and using  array_rand($sterren, 2); this returns 3 or 4 but no 5.  array_rand($sterren, 3) returns only the value 3.

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3: Feel free to ask a new question. Remember to add more details in the questions you ask, such as what you've tried, what *exactly* you are trying to achieve, what the expected result is, what the difference between the expected result and the effective result is. Also, the variable names are not very descriptive and would confuse people -- I suggest you use more descriptive variables names, like `$array`, `$random_keys` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I will open a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the optional `$num` parameter is set, `array_rand()` returns `$num` random keys. In this case, you're setting the second parameter `1`, so you'll get a single key.   You just need to echo the corresponding array element:

Change:

```
$sterrenf = $sterren[$sterrenr[0]];
```

to:

```
$sterrenf = $sterren[$sterrenr];
```

Comment: Thanks but it still only outputs 3 and 4.

Comment: Actually now it outputs 3,4 or 5. So yes this is the solution. But could you be so kind to explain me why ? Because I dont see the difference. 

When I do :

$sterrenr = array_rand($sterren, 3);
This will generate $sterrenr[0],[1],[2] holding the values 3,4 or 5.

Comment: @AmalMurali : "+1" for the demo.!!

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3: `$sterrenf = $sterren[$sterrenr[0]];` -- you're trying to access the first array element when **$sterrenr is not an array** (as `var_dump($sterrenr);` would tell you).

Comment: Ok but with $sterrenr = array_rand($sterren, 3); $sterrenr would be an array holding 3 randomized values of $sterren. Still this does not work.

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3 see by answer below, if you're still wondering why it doesn't work;)

Answer (score 0):

Very easy look with:

First to retrieve the three elements point array_rand to (~,3) not to (~,1).

Second to random as you think is by shuffle in php not by array_rand because array_rand will return a random selection but will rearrange them inside it so after it use "shuffle()" on the output of array_rand "result array" like this what i mean:

```
$sterren = array("3","4","5");
$sterrenr = array_rand($sterren, 3);
shuffle($sterrenr);
$sterrenf = $sterren[$sterrenr[0]];
echo $sterrenf;
```